# Why is ArrayFormula causing empty value "" to register > 0

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Sample sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16huMKzeqbg3gho5klvRj91878H1ZARIs4F9RVRwE9M0

Tab: Week 45-48

I have this arrayformula set to pull $ amount data from another tab:

Cell F42:

`=IFERROR(IF(value(F4) = value(Settings!$B$26),ArrayFormula(INDEX(FullReport!$A:$A,SMALL(IF("Labour Cost"=FullReport!$A:$A,ROW(FullReport!$A:$A)+1),1))),""),0)`

It leaves a blank field if the value is empty.  I have another formula set to read this data if the value is greater than $0.00

Cell D38:

`=SUM(((IF(C42 > 0, C42,C41)) + (IF(D42 > 0, D42,D41)) + (IF(E42 > 0, E42,E41)) + (IF(F42 > 0, F42,F41)) + (IF(G42 > 0, G42,G41)) + (IF(H42 > 0, H42,H41)) + (IF(I42 > 0, I42,I41))))+B39`

Unfortunately it seems the blank field "" being generated in cell F42 is causing cell D38 to register as a value greater than $0.00 and is throwing the expected results off.

Looking for a way around this, thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I looked into your sheet but can't say what exactly are you after nor where exactly. can you edit your question and explain in more detail what is your issue

Comment: @player0 Updated original question with more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run `=IF(F42 > 0, F42, F41)` the output is blank cell so all the concerns about arrayformula should be discarded.

on the other hand, there is `=IF(D42 > 0, D42, D41)` which results in `FALSE` so in your `SUM` there are summed 4 values: **B39 + C41 + D41 + E41** resulting in `$5,571.08` (see the red table)

[image: 0]

if you expect the sum to exclude **D41** value your `IF` formula should be:

```
=IF((D42=0)+(D42=""), D42, D41)
```

the `+` sign acts as `OR`

---

or you can just use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(IF(C42:I42*1>0, C41:I41, C42:I42)))+B39
```

[image: 0]